# C++ built-in fixed-width types with no additional includes

Tags: c++

According to this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer, such types like `int32_t` are **`Defined in header <cstdint>`**.

VS2019/C++17 doesn't compile `int32_t i = 5;` until I `#include <cstdint>`.

Is it normal that I need including some headers to use the built-in types? Are there other fixed-width types/typedefs/macros/whatever to use with no additional includes?

Comment: Yes, they are not built-in types but aliases.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the built-in types are things like `int`, `long int`, `unsigned long int`, etc., which don't have exact guarantees about how many bytes of memory their representations take up. You need to include the header if you want to specify that.

Comment: Apart from the [fundamental types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types), you are required to include the proper header files to assure access to the types in the standard library - or _any_ library.

Comment: `int` is a built-in type.  The point of "defined in header" is that it is **not** built-in

Comment: Thank you, guys, I've got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it normal that I need including some headers to use built-in types?

`int32_t` is not a "built-in" (or fundamental, as the standard calls them) type. It is a type alias defined in the standard library. Yes, it is normal to need to include headers in order to use the standard library.

Note that `<cstdint>` is not guaranteed to define `::int32_t`. It is only guaranteed to define `std::int32_t` and may define `::int32_t`. As such, you should not rely on `::int32_t` being defined by `<cstdint>`.

> Are there other fixed-width types/typedefs/macros/whatever to use with no additional includes?

There are no type aliases that can be used without defining them. Standard type aliases, such as the fixed width integer aliases, can only be defined by including the standard header which defines them.

Typically macros are like that as well, but there are some predefined macros which can be used without including anything such as `__cplusplus` for example. The full list of these is in the standard section [cpp.predefined].

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the [fundamental types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types), you are required to include the proper header file to assure access to the types in the standard library.

The fixed width types you mention are all `typedef`ined to map to fundamental types.

Some of them are even optional. Take `uint8_t` for example: On a platform where an `unsigned char` is *not* 1 byte (octet), `uint8_t` may not exist.

If you require a type of *at least* 8 bits, you can use `uint_least8_t`. If you want a compilation error (because your program would break) in the absence of the type being exactly 8 bits, use `uint8_t` etc.